# Change background image using jquery and escape double quotes

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the background image using jquery.

the user enter the url to his background in an input text and when clicking a button the background image change, simple as that.

this is the code i used.

```
$(".change_bg").on("click",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var bg = $(".bg_input").val();

    $("table").css("background-image", "url("+bg+")");  

});
```

this code works great.

My problem is when i open firebug i see this.

```
<table style="background-image: url("the_new_background-image");" >
```

How can i remove the double quotes inside the url and get this.

```
<table style="background-image: url(the_new_background-image);" >
```

The whole HTML code will be sent to a server and get downloaded, so when i try to open the downloaded HTML file in the browser the background image doesn't show up.

i try to us this code and replace the double quotes but i didn't succed.

```
$("table").css("background-image", ("url('"+bg+"')").replace(/"/g,""));
```

Please some one help.

Comment: I don't understand where comes from your issue. Any online sample to let us test it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/ThF5Z/

Comment: Just one thing, if i understand your problem correctly, you should set background image url as absolute, if used not directly from server

Comment: @nbar actualy my code works fine whene changing the background... this is not what i want.
i want a way to delete the double quotes inside the 'url("...")' and have this 'url(...)'

Comment: Oh, I found your "problem" now. It is firebug that insert the quotes. Test the same code in chrome and you dont see quotes. On the whole there is no problem and nothing to fix

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code should work fine. The url() parameter does not need quotes, url(urltofile) works just as fine as url("urltofile").

[See a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UE35h/)

```
$(".change_bg").on("click",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var bg = $(".bg_input").val().replace("\"", "");

    $("table").css("background-image", "url("+bg+")");  

});
```

Comment: url(urltofile) works indeed. weird to put a string without "".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("table").css("background-image", "url(" + escape(bg) + ")");
```

Or even better,

```
var bg = escape($(".bg_input").val());
```

Escape before doing anything else!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code as you can see here: jsfiddle.net/ThF5Z

```
$("#me").on("click",function(e){
console.log("click");
    e.preventDefault();

    var bg = $("input").val();

    $("#me").css("background-image", "url("+bg+")");  

});
```

The quotes comes from firebug/firefox. Test the same code in chrome and you don't have quotes. There is nothing to fix.

Comment: You are totaly right, there is no quotes in chrome, any idea why firfox insert quotes around the image url ?